# Getting the sum off an array

Tags: php

Hi everyone i am looking to get a sum out off array elements. out of the following array.
I want the final sum off size key added up.

```
    Array
(
    [105 - Screama & Merkury - Kiss Me (Ft. Farah).mp3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 105 - Screama & Merkury - Kiss Me (Ft. Farah).mp3
            [time] => 1309246242
            [size] => 5912295
            [hash] => ae6c5dda2b75a4fcbd9f36394f744717
        )

    [106 - The Fives - It's What You Do (Ft. Vanya Taylor).mp3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 106 - The Fives - It's What You Do (Ft. Vanya Taylor).mp3
            [time] => 1309246243
            [size] => 6361223
            [hash] => 8898827f715e88c7c667bcbc716086f6
        )

    [107 - Crazy Cousinz - Funky Anthem (Ft. MC Versatile).mp3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 107 - Crazy Cousinz - Funky Anthem (Ft. MC Versatile).mp3
            [time] => 1309246243
            [size] => 4841021
            [hash] => dce7d5d3b781625f3e74eab58efc3779
        )

    [108 - Funky Dee - Are You Gonna Bang.mp3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 108 - Funky Dee - Are You Gonna Bang.mp3
            [time] => 1309246243
            [size] => 3766429
            [hash] => 6605b648ead22ace8e5ce77e3c53801f
        )

    [109 - Mr M - Dash Down.mp3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 109 - Mr M - Dash Down.mp3
            [time] => 1309246243
            [size] => 4099700
            [hash] => 1dcb8a77de83ec0315fc4431ff31f311
        )

    [110 - S-X - Woooo.mp3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 110 - S-X - Woooo.mp3
            [time] => 1309246243
            [size] => 3364615
            [hash] => 5069b5956c99bcf468bc3fd00178cc22
        )

    [111 - Lil Silva - Different VIP.mp3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 111 - Lil Silva - Different VIP.mp3
            [time] => 1309246244
            [size] => 4019543
            [hash] => 8b73799089a8a8e64cdff8436fa8c446
        )

    [crossdomain.xml] => Array
        (
            [name] => crossdomain.xml
            [time] => 1309245738
            [size] => 216
            [hash] => 3cb3c78f77460e93c87faec3b50a8434
        )

)
```

I want to add up all the size keys. how can i do this i am looking a using array_sum but dont now how to change the array to just show the size key any help please.

;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$totalSize = 0;
foreach($yourarray as $file => $attr) {
    $totalSize += (int) $attr['size'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP5.3 solution

```
$totalSize = array_reduce($array, function ($currentTotalSize, $attr) {
  return $currentTotalSize + $attr['size'];
}, 0);
```

or

```
$totalSize = array_sum(array_map(function ($attr) {
  return $attr['size'];
}, $array));
```

The first one is more or less a different notation for a `foreach´-loop, but should be slightly (negligible?) faster and for users familiar with functional programming its easy understandable.

The second one is "the naive approach" by first extracting the size of all entries and then sum it up.

Comment: Wouldn't $totalSize be out of scope?

Comment: I should give them different names. `$totalSize` in front of the expression and `$totalSize` as the closure parameter are different variables.

Comment: Yes you're right, haven't used `array_reduce()` before. Just did a readup on [php.net/array_reduce](http://dk.php.net/array_reduce) - I learn every day, I like it!